# Fetch rows where certain criteria meets in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to fetch the rows per <kbd>**code** (where serial is 2)</kbd> **where** `value of new (where serial is 2) >= value of sold (where serial is 1)` **and**
`value of new (where serial is 2) < value of sold (where serial is 2)`

**Formula:** `new[2] >= sold[1] and new[2] < sold[2]` , [2]/[1] are the serial (and thats why I tried to put the index on serial).

**Sample Dataframe (data):** `data.set_index('serial')`

|  | code | serial | date | new | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20113 | 1 | 2019-01-30 | 1344.4 | 1344.95 |
| 1 | 20113 | 2 | 2019-02-30 | 1345.35 | 1344.9 |
| 2 | 20113 | 3 | 2019-03-30 | 1347.4 | 1345.35 |
| 3 | 20286 | 1 | 2019-01-30 | 590.55 | 590.15 |
| 4 | 20286 | 2 | 2019-02-30 | 590.15 | 590.55 |
| 5 | 20286 | 3 | 2019-03-30 | 590.4 | 590.15 |

**It gives an error:**

> File
> "C:#########\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 3361, in get_loc
> return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)   File "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 76, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas_libs\index.pyx", line 108, in
> pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc   File
> "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5198, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item   File
> "pandas_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 5206, in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item KeyError: True
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "F:\python_projects#########\testing.py", line 12, in 
> status = globals()[f"strategy_{row[0]}"].pre_check_condition_panda(5,now)#(row[2],now)
> File "F:\python_projects#########\strategy.py", line 88, in
> pre_check_condition_panda
> data1 = data[(data.open[2] >= data.close[1]) & (data.open[2] > data.close[2])]   File
> "C:#########\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line
> 3455, in **getitem**
> indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)   File "C:#########\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py",
> line 3363, in get_loc
> raise KeyError(key) from err KeyError: True

**My code:**

```
data1 = data[(data.new[2] >= data.sold[1]) & (data.new[2] < data.sold[2])]
print(data1)
```

**Expected Result:**

|  | code | serial | date | new | sold |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 20286 | 2 | 2019-02-30 | 590.15 | 590.55 |

Comment: there is no column `open` or `close` in your dataframe example

Comment: @anky just noticed that, have updated!

Comment: `(df.new[2] >= df.sold[1]) & (df.new[2] < df.sold[2])` gives a scalar value (`False`) , how do you slice a dataframe with that? could you explain in words what you are trying to do? ]

Comment: @anky have provided more explanation what needs to be fetched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using stack/unstack you can get the "code" that matches the requirement, but the condition to get only serial == 2 is unclear:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['code', 'serial']).unstack()
(df2.loc[df2[('new', 2)].ge(df2[('sold', 1)])
        &df2[('new', 2)].lt(df2[('sold', 2)])
        ]
    .stack(level=1)
    .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
    code  serial        date     new    sold
0  20286       1  2019-01-30  590.55  590.15
1  20286       2  2019-02-30  590.15  590.55
2  20286       3  2019-03-30  590.40  590.15
```

If you only want serial == 2, you can add `.query('serial == 2')`:

```
df2 = df.set_index(['code', 'serial']).unstack()
(df2.loc[df2[('new', 2)].ge(df2[('sold', 1)])
        &df2[('new', 2)].lt(df2[('sold', 2)])
        ]
    .stack(level=1)
    .reset_index()
    .query('serial == 2')
)
```

output:

```
    code  serial        date     new    sold
1  20286       2  2019-02-30  590.15  590.55
```

Comment: Could you please share docs where I can get the reference to `ge` and `lt` so that I can look what else we can use in my other formulas. Also, why `stack(1)`? Why not `stack()` or `stack(0)` or `stack(2)`?

Comment: [`ge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html) is identical to using `>=` and [`lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) to `<`. [`stack(1)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) means stack level1 (=the second level of the index)

Comment: @mozway thanks, it helped me to fetch the exact way I wanted, having some useless question:- here its just small condition, but in reality I am using more than 15 conditions, will the order of condition vary the performances?

Comment: The order should not matter, I think all are calculated anyway as it's vectorial (unlike pure python where it might better to put the cheap conditions first)